# How to change arguments of UndirectedEdge

Tags: graphs-and-networks, replacement

There is a list of `UndirectedEdge`:

```
list = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 4 <-> 5}
```

How to change it to:

```
{101 <-> 102, 102 <-> 103,  104 <-> 105}
```

?

---

I tried :

```
list /. UndirectedEdge[x_, y_] /; x :> x + 100;
list /. x_ <-> y_ /; x + 100 <-> y + 100;
list /. x_UndirectedEdge /; First[x] <-> Last[x]
list /. x_UndirectedEdge /; x :> First[x] <-> Last[x];
```

but they are not working correctly.

Comment: You nearly had it! You're second attempt is very close, you have the correct pattern to match `x_ \[UndirectedEdge] y_`, and the correct replacement `x + 100 \[UndirectedEdge] y + 100` the only minor mistake is that you used `Condition`, `\;`, which should be `RuleDelayed`, `:>`. Therefore try: `list /. x_ \[UndirectedEdge] y_ :> x + 100 \[UndirectedEdge] y + 100;`

Comment: `list /. x_Integer :> 100 + x`

Answer (score 2):

In such cases `Cases`is your friend ;-). You can use it to identify and modify arguments in the following way:

```
Cases[list, 
 UndirectedEdge[x_, y_] :> UndirectedEdge[100 + x, 100 + y]]
(*{101 <-> 102, 102 <-> 103, 104 <-> 105}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3,  4 <-> 5};

list /. x_Integer :> 100 + x
Map[100 + # &, list, {-1}]
Replace[list, x_ :> 100 + x, {2}]
MapAt[100 + # &, list, {{All, 1}, {All, 2}}]
UndirectedEdge @@@ (100 + {##} & @@@ list)
EdgeList @ VertexReplace[list, v_ :> 100 + v]
```

all give

> {101 <-> 102, 102 <-> 103, 104 <-> 105}